# Frameworks supporting layered customisation like adf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oracle-adf, customising

Is any other framework that supports layered customisation(Adding features in layers say for country and on top of it for specific client to core application without modifying the existing source code.) on UI as provided by Oracle ADF?

Looking for some javascript based UI framework.

Comment: I am afraid there are not many experienced ADF developers with a good knowledge of other web frameworks. The question is good, though.